# How to handle the crabs in Adventure Time - Time Tangle?

Tags: adventure-time-time-tangle

What's the best way to handle giant crabs in Adventure Time Time Tangle? You can't jump over them, you can't punch through them and you can't go around them. 
Actually, you can jump if their claws are down, if you land the punch at just the right time you come to a stop long enough to maybe get around.

At present if I come up against a crab it's 50/50 if I'll get past or lose a heart.

Interestingly in the gallery with hints, this 'baddie' is greyed out so you can't get to the tips - which are sometimes helpful.

Comment: 'Baddies' get un-greyed in the gallery only when you beat them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a charged punch to crack through that jerk crab's shell!

Comment: Please expand your answer

Comment: By 'charged punch' they mean press and hold punch for three seconds to get a 'wind up' and a more powerful punch. It's not that easy - especially when they come out of the mist - but I can confirm that this approach does work (by fluke - preparing the charged punch and holding it until a crab came along).